# What screen recorder will work with SwayWM?

Tags: sway

I'm using SwayWM what screen recorder or capture program can I use with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`wf-recorder` can do that](https://github.com/ammen99/wf-recorder). You can capture the whole screen with

```
wf-recorder -f out.mkv
```

Or just a section of it with (requires `slurp` be installed to)

```
wf-recorder -g "$(slurp)"
```

Use the `--audio` flag to capture audio.